# Release Symfony2 project to the web

Tags: symfony, web-deployment

I have almost finished the development of a project developed with Symfony2, and wish to put the project online.

However, I suppose there are a lot of things that need to be done so that everything works ok. I suppose, the dev mode needs to be disabled etc....What needs to be done and how?

### What are the most important things to do on a Symfony2 project that will be available to everyone on the web?

Comment: You should read [this](http://astrails.com/blog/2008/12/17/deployment-process-requirements). I first tried Capifony/Capistrano, had some troubles, read its source files, and ended up writing my own deployment script in bash with all what I learned from that article, Capifony's source files, and from @thecatontheflat's posts. I had to learn bash in the process, and it was totally worth it. Now deploying is a pleasure. Also, no more Ruby nonsense.

Comment: @ChocoDeveloper This is a great comment! Many thanks. Yeah, as the author mentions, it is hard to know how to do the deployment properly!! Maybe it would be worth sharing an example of a bash script that handles deployment, maybe on [gist](https://gist.github.com/) Do you think this would be a good idea? Would you be happy to share a draft of the script or a piece of it maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use [Capifony](http://capifony.org/) for deployment. It does a lot of stuff out of the box and you can make it run any custom commands you need. See its documentation for details.

Regarding the dev mode, unless you've removed the IP checks from `app_dev.php`, you don't have to worry about deploying it. Of course, if you wish, you can tell Capifony to delete it on deployment.

Comment: Thanks @elnur. I am very likely to go with Capifony. What do you recommend in terms of versioning tool? Do you think versioning is absolutely necessary?

Comment: I use [Git](http://git-scm.com/) and recommend it wholeheartedly. I use it even on projects I'm developing alone — can't imagine myself writing something longer than a day without a VCS.

Comment: Awesome! That's huge help :-)

Answer (score 3):

The best way to handle deployment is to create "build" script, which will:

1. Remove all folders and files with tests from your bundles and vendors.
2. Remove `app_dev.php` file
3. Make sure that `app/cache` and `app/logs` are fully writable/readable.
4. Packs your project into archive (rpm f.e.)

Then, before deployment, you should create tag in your project - so it will mean, that certain version of your application is released (I recommend to follow this [git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)).

1. Create tag.
2. Run your build script
3. Upload archive to host
4. Unpack
5. Enjoy your project

Comment: Thanks @thecatontheflat. What do you use to create a "build" script? Do you recommend Capifony too?

Comment: Build script is shell script, that fetches certain tag, finds/removes files/folders, executes symfony2 console commands (assetic dump, assets install) and so on. We usually execute it like `sh build.sh your-tag`

Comment: Great! That is very handy. Thanks @thecatontheflat. I'll see if I can find an example of this, especially the part with the tag, the rest should be basic shell scripting I suppose. I never heard of the concept of tags before so, many thanks :-)

Answer (score 3):

Im currently researching the same thing.

The first thing you have to consider is "how professional" you want to deploy. There are a lot of tools you can use:

1. Continous Integration Server ( e.g. Hudson, Jenkins)
2. Build Tools (e.g. Phing, Capistrano --> Capifony, Shell scripts)
3. Versioning Tools (e.g. Git, SVN)

I think the simplest setup is using only a Build tool and i guess you are already using some kind of versioning.

Depending on which tool you use, the setup is different, but I think there are some things you should consider with your application (maybe not all are applicable to your application)

- Creating a Tag in your Versioning
- Copying the new Code in an folder on production
  --> if you are in a new folder you dont need to clear the cache and logs, since these shouldnt be in your versioning the first time.
- loading composer (if youre using it)
- installing vendors
- updating database schema
- install assets from your bundles
- move symlink from current version to the folder of the new site

These are the things I currently need for my application for production deployment, if you deploy to an test environment you should load fixtures and run your testscripts as well.

Answer (score 0):

One other option that is very well described [here](http://blog.sznapka.pl/deploying-symfony2-applications-with-ant/) is to deploy the Symfony2 application with **Apache Ant**. [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) is a Java library and command-line tool whose mission is to drive processes described in build files as targets and extension points dependent upon each other.